# how to grab value of textbox and insert into database in joomla

Tags: joomla

```
function create(){ 

$doc=JFactory::getDocument(); 
$post = JRequest::getVar('post');
$doc->addStyleSheet(JURI::root().'media/com_mycomp/css/frontend_create_task.css');
$doc->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_mycomp/js/frontend_createtask.js');

echo "Welcome to Create"; 
$db=JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query=$db->getQuery(true); 
$query="INSERT INTO #__mycomp_posts (title,body) VALUES ('front Post','This is post body')";
$db->setQuery($query); 
$db->query();

    echo "<div id='welcome'>".JText::_('COM_MYCOMP_TASK_CREATE')."</div>";
}
```

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: no errors, I only had this  function in controller that inserts into database. But i need to take value from textbox and insert in database. What files and folders should i create for it??

Comment: Wht are you trying to achieve ? Submitting a form and saving Data on DB ? check out the MVC component tutorial of Joomla. http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction

Comment: not subit the form only saving data in DB by taking values from textboxes.

Comment: check this http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: Plz can you provide me any simple joomla component that you develop that takes user input and saves into database?

Comment: take a look at this http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Example_of_a_frontend_update_function and download sample here http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/11394/58397/com_helloworld-1.6-part07.zip